# Entity set connection timeout

Tags: c#, entity-framework, timeout

How can I set the value of connectionTimeout (not commandTimeout) of context by coding (not in connection string) ?
This is readonly:

```
DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 10;
```

Thanks

**Udpate:**

My probleme is to test if my context is available quickly and the default time is to long ? 
I tried this :

```
        int? oldTimeOut = RepositoryDbContext.Database.CommandTimeout;

        try
        {
            RepositoryDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 10; //readonly
            RepositoryDbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 10; // doesn't work, the value stay the same
            RepositoryDbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            RepositoryDbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            RepositoryDbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = oldTimeOut;
        }
```

But I can't change the connectionTimeout is readOnly and the commandTimeout doesn't set the value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any option to change the connection timeout via the EF API.  You can however change the connection string at runtime.  You could parse the configured connection string and change the timeout parameter, or add one if it does not exist.

If you are working with SQL Server only, I would suggest using [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).  Use the constructor that takes an [existing connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7z89tex(v=vs.110).aspx), change the [ConnectTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.connecttimeout(v=vs.110).aspx), get the [modified connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx), and use that connection string when [constructing your DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx).

Depending on what you are actually trying to solve, one alternative might be to use SlowCheetah to easily generate the web.config, with different configuration strings, for different build types.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment...

Try something like

```
string normalConnectionString = RepositoryDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
var connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(normalConnectionString);
connectionBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 10;
string testConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString;

using (var testRepositoryDbContext = new RepositoryDbContextType(testConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        testRepositoryDbContext.Database.Connection.Open();    
        testRepositoryDbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a code example.  It is not shown what type RepositoryDbContext is, so I called it RepositoryDbContextType.  You will need to insert the correct type name.

Comment: thanks but I can't use and modify connection string, because I use entity code first configurations. Is there an other way ?

Comment: @Julian50: I use code first too.  This should work.  Did you try it?

Comment: arf I very sorry:) but I use a "generic data access layer" in a separate projet. In this projet I don't have dbcontext where I can put conntection string. My RepositoryDbContext is a context from entity configuration. I don't know if is clear... but can't use contection string..

Comment: Can you perhaps configure a separate TestRepositoryDbContext in entity configuration, that is the same as RepositoryDbContext except for the connection timeout?  That's the only option I can think of.

Comment: Forgive me Eric for my previous comments on your solution.Finally It works!And I find how to add it in my projet properly even with severals configuration. Thank you very much. The night helps ;)